# Emacs- visual-line-mode and latex tabular environment

Tags: latex, auctex

I am using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 with visual-line-mode turned on for LaTeX editing. This works great, except in tabular environments, where it would be nice to have the word-wrapping turned off. Is this even possible? My Lisp skills are limited so not sure where to start with this.

Comment: No, it is not possible out of the box -- there are two or three  essentially duplicate threads here or on stackoverflow, but I am away from a computer at this time.  The concept is one buffer with BOTH word-wrap and truncate-lines at different locations.  Some people have expressest interest in writing a workaround, but I don't believe anyone ever did.  My recommendation has been to narrow to region and have that narrowed region be word-wrap or truncate-lines, and the widen version will be the opposite of the narrowed version.

Comment: Thank very you for your comments. I did search, but nothing came up, guess I used the wrong keywords.